# Android: how to hide the button when the scroll reach the end

Tags: android, layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I have layout with scrollview  at the top and the button at the bottom of the screen. I want to hide this button when I scroll down and show it when I reach end of scroll view. How I can realize this?

red-`Button`, `ScrollView`-blue.
[image]

Comment: Add your codes here

Comment: Is it a `scrollview` or a `list / recyclerview` in there ? Without showing what you've tried won't be easy to answer you.

Answer (score 3):

try this 
**main_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Submit" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In **Activity Class**

```
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    Button mSubmit = findViewById(R.id.submit);


    mRecyclerView .addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                         //dx horizontal distance scrolled in pixels
                         //dy vertical distance scrolled in pixels
                        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                        if (dy > 0 && mSubmit.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                            mSubmit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else if (dy < 0 && mSubmit.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                            mSubmit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                });
```